# How to save labels in InCopy?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, data-persistence, adobe-incopy

It seems that when InCopy saves a document, programmatically added labels are lost. For instance, if I do this:

```
app.activeDocument.insertLabel('myLabel', 'magicString');
```

The label is effectively added, as evidenced by this:

```
app.activeDocument.extractLabel('myLabel'); // Yields 'magicString'
```

But if I save, close and reopen the document (all manually), and do:

```
app.activeDocument.extractLabel('myLabel');
```

The result is not `'magicString'`, but `''`.

In InDesign, however, after the exact same operations, the result is `'magicString'`.
Is there any way to make the labels persistant in InCopy?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
app.activeDocument.stories[0].insertLabel('myLabel', 'magicString');
```

InCopy file is a single story and it seems that story maintains the label better than the document. Then to extract your label you would do:

```
app.activeDocument.stories[0].extractLabel('myLabel');
```